# can php curl progress returning percentage?

Tags: php, curl

I use this code to return percentage downloading data with php curl

```
<?php 
 $url  = 'http://exemple.com/';
 $path = 'index.html';
 $fp = fopen($path, 'w');    

$ch=curl_init() or die("ERROR|<b>Error:</b> cURL Error");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

//####################################################//
// This is required to curl give us some progress
// if this is not set to false the progress function never
// gets called
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);

// Set up the callback
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'callback');

// Big buffer less progress info/callbacks
// Small buffer more progress info/callbacks
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
//####################################################//

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Progress callback function ,

```
function callback($download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded)
{
  $percent = $downloaded/$download_size;
  // Do something with $percent
  echo sprintf('%.2f', $percent*100);
  echo '%<br/>';
  echo str_repeat(' ', 8192);
  flush();
}
```

I think, i do mistake in the progress callback function, i try method to get bits received but still not work to here is the method.

```
bps = time elapsed / size received;
Remaining Time = (Total size - size received) * bps
```

---

but i still get this in the result:

```
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
0.00%
```

why this not work , there is any other way to do the trick?

Comment: no comments , lol it's hard or what?

Answer (score 2):

```
function handle() {
    $this->db->prep("
        update
            `links`
        set
            `status`='toDownload',
            `processStartDate` = now()
        where
            `id` = ?
        limit
            1
        ;
    ")->bind([$this->link->id]);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $fp = fopen(__DIR__ . "/test.data", "w+");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->link->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    $t = new DateTime();
    $db = $this->db;
    $linkId = $this->link->id;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function ($resource,$download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) use ($t, $db, $linkId) {
        if ($download_size > 0 && ($t < new DateTime())) {
            $p = round(($downloaded / $download_size) * 100, 2);
            echo "download_size: $download_size, downloaded: $downloaded,   p: $p%,     t: ".$t->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\r\n";
            $t->modify("+1 second");
            $db->prep("update links set `progress` =? where `id`=? limit 1")->bind([
                $p,
                $linkId
            ]);
        }
    });
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
    $this->db->prep("update `links` set `progress`='100', `status`='done' where `id` = ? limit 1")->bind([
        $this->link->id
    ]);
}
```